# Vector in affine subspace with minimal angle to other vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space with scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and norm $\lvert v \rvert:=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$ for $v\in V$. Let $Z\subset V$ be an affine subspace (i.e. $Z=b + W$ for $b\in V$ and $W\subset V$ a subspace). Finally, let $0\neq v\in V$ be a vector in $V$ which is not parallel to $Z$ (i.e. $v\notin W$).
I would like to compute (explicitely) the point $z\in Z$, such that the vector $v_z\in V$ pointing to $z\in Z$ minimizes the angle to $v$, or equivalently, which maximizes $\cos(\measuredangle(v,v_z))=\frac{\langle v, v_z\rangle}{\lvert v \rvert \lvert v_z \rvert}$ for $z\in Z$.

I know how to calculate with linear algebra the $z\in Z$ which minimizes the distance between $Z$ and $\mathbb{R} v$ and I assumed erroneously that this is the same as the vector which minimizes the angle to $v$. I'm wondering if there is a similar (linear algebra) solution for minimizing the angle.

Background is a task from applied statistics where a matrix, which represents the structure of a system, is calibrated to a vector, which represents the quantity of the same system. The calibration should affect the structrue of the matrix as little as possible. This is measured by means of the angle between the uncalibrated and calibrated matrix.

Comment: Isn’t this just the intersection of $Z$ and the ray $\lambda v$, $\lambda\ge0$?

Comment: In general $Z$ and $\mathbb{R}v$ don't intersect, even if $v$ is not parallel to $W$ (we are in higher dimensions). In the cases I am interested in we have $\dim{W}+1<\dim{V}$.

Comment: If there’s no intersection, there might not be any element of $Z$ that minimizes the angle. Consider the case of the plane $(a,1,b,0)\in\mathbb R^4$ and $v=(1,0,0,0)$, for which the angle can be made arbitrarily small by taking large enough $a$, but there is no point on the plane for which the angle is $0$.

Comment: I agree, but in your example $v$ is parellel to $Z$ (i.e.$ v\in W$). If this is the case, there is never a vector $v_z$ for $z\in Z$ which minimizes the angle to $v$. I edit the question to precise that.

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward multivariable calculus problem. If you parameterize $Z$, the expression for the angle cosine becomes the quotient of a linear term and the square root of a quadratic. Finding the stationary points, if any, is then a matter of solving a system of quadratic equations. Alternatively, you could solve this using Lagrange multipliers, which will lead you to the same sort of system to solve, I believe.

Comment: There still may not be a minimal angle, though, even when $v$ is not parallel to $Z$. E.g., $Z=\{(-1,\lambda,\lambda) \mid \lambda\in\mathbb R\}$ and $v=(1,1,0)$. Loosely speaking, $v$ has to point “toward” $Z$ for there to be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a simple geometric solution by linear algebra: let $Z'$ be the smallest sub vector space of $V$ which contains $Z$, and $v'$ the projection of $v$ to $Z'$. Find the unique $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha \cdot v' \in Z$. The latter is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We seek to maximize the function $f:\mathbf z \mapsto {\mathbf v^T\mathbf z \over \|\mathbf v\| \|\mathbf z\|}$ for $\mathbf z \in Z$. The critical points of $f$, if any, satisfy $$\operatorname{d}f = {(\mathbf z^T\mathbf z) \mathbf v^T - (\mathbf v^T \mathbf z)\mathbf z^T \over \|\mathbf v\| \|\mathbf z\|^3}\operatorname{d}{\mathbf z} = \mathbf 0.$$ We can discard the denominator, leaving the equation $$\left((\mathbf z^T\mathbf z) \mathbf v^T - (\mathbf v^T \mathbf z)\mathbf z^T \right) \operatorname{d}{\mathbf z} = 0. \tag1 $$ With some abuse of notation, let the matrix $W = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf w_1 & \cdots & \mathbf w_m \end{bmatrix}$, where $\{\mathbf w_1, \dots, \mathbf w_m\}$ is a basis for the subspace $W$. We can then parameterize $Z$ via the pullback $\alpha:\mathbb R^m \to Z$ given by $$\alpha: \mathbf x \mapsto W\mathbf x+\mathbf b$$ so that $\alpha^*\operatorname{d}\mathbf z=W$ and the equation to be solved becomes $$\left((W\mathbf x+\mathbf b)^T (W\mathbf x+\mathbf b) \mathbf v^T - \mathbf v^T (W\mathbf x+\mathbf b) (W\mathbf x+\mathbf b)^T \right) W = 0. \tag 2$$ If $\mathbf x=(x_1,\dots,x_m)^T$, this is a system of quadratic equations in the variables $x_k$, the individual equations being $$(W\mathbf x+\mathbf b)^T (W\mathbf x+\mathbf b) \, \mathbf v^T \mathbf w_k - \mathbf v^T (W\mathbf x+\mathbf b) \, (W\mathbf x+\mathbf b)^T \mathbf w_k = 0. \tag 3$$

For a geometrical interpretation of these equations, we pull a factor of $(\mathbf z^T \mathbf z)^{-1}$ back into (1), substitute for $\operatorname{d}{\mathbf z}$ and transpose: $$W^T \left(\mathbf v - {\mathbf v^T \mathbf z \over \mathbf z^T \mathbf z} \mathbf z \right) = 0.$$ The parenthesized term is the orthogonal rejection of $\mathbf v$ from $\mathbf z$, so this equation says that the critical points of $f$ are those $\mathbf z$ for which the orthogonal rejection of $\mathbf v$ from $\mathbf z$ is also orthogonal to the subspace $W$. This means that we can find these values by intersecting a quadric with $W^\perp$. I don’t think that this view really simplifies the equations to be solved, but it might point the way toward developing a direct computation akin to the one for computing the intersection of a line and a conic.

For example, let $\mathbf z=(1,0,0,0)^T+\lambda(0,1,0,1)^T+\mu(0,0,1,0)^T$, $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb R$ and $\mathbf v = (1,1,0,0)^T$. Then $$\alpha^*f(\lambda,\mu) = {(1,1,0,0) (1,\lambda,\mu,\lambda)^T \over \|(1,1,0,0)\| \|(1,\lambda,\mu,\lambda)\|} = {1+\lambda \over \sqrt2 \sqrt{1+2\lambda^2+\mu^2}}.$$ Differentiating and taking the numerators produces the system $$\begin{align} 1-2\lambda+\mu^2 &= 0 \\ -(1+\lambda)\mu &= 0 \end{align}$$ with solution $\lambda=\frac12$, $\mu=0$, giving $\mathbf z=\left(1,\frac12,0,\frac12\right)^T$ with ${\sqrt3\over2}$ for the cosine of the angle. We compare the equations that result from substituting into (1): $$\left( (1+2\lambda^2+\mu^2)\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\end{bmatrix} - (1+\lambda)\begin{bmatrix}1&\lambda&\mu&\lambda\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\\0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} = (1+2\lambda^2+\mu^2)\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix} - (1+\lambda)\begin{bmatrix}2\lambda&\mu\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1-2\lambda+\mu^2 & -(1+\lambda)\mu\end{bmatrix}.$$

These critical points might not be maxima, however. For instance, taking $\mathbf v=(-1,-1,0,0)^T$ instead in the preceding example gives the same critical point, but now $f(\mathbf z)=-{\sqrt3\over2}$, a local (and global) minimum. (This should be apparent without going through all of the calculations again since all we’ve done is change the sign of $f$.)

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot!